# Dart getting 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>' analysis error

Tags: flutter, dart, analysis

this below `json` code is our server response which i parse that with this code:

```dart
@freezed
abstract class UserModel with _$UserModel {
  const factory UserModel({
    required int id,
    @JsonKey(name: 'name_family') required String nameFamily,
    @JsonKey(name: 'mobile_number') required String mobileNumber,
    @JsonKey(name: 'baker_profile') required BakerProfileModel bakerProfile,
  }) = _UserModel;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserModelFromJson(json);
}

final onlineBakers = List<UserModel>.from(
  success['data'].map(
    (data) => UserModel.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>),
  ),
).toList();
```

here i don't have any problem and i can get all of values with `onlineBakers` variable, but i can't resolve analysis error in `AndroidStudio` as this error for this part of code:

```
The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

```dart
success['data'].map(
  (data) => UserModel.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>),
),
```

when i try to use `as List<UserModel>` i get another error, for example:

```dart
success['data'].map(
  (data) => UserModel.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>),
) as List<UserModel>,
```

error:

```
type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<UserModel>' in type cast
```

response `json`:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "user_type": "baker",
    "name_family": "test",
    "mobile_number": "09087549785",
    "active": 1,
    "baker_profile": {
      "id": 9,
      "user_id": 6,
      "province_id": 19,
      "city_id": 729,
      "neighbourhood_id": 2,
      "profile_image": "baker_profiles_images/pUZtdPNCKoQnXbKWBwUnciK7Yo01fG1IMUggzgVK.png",
      "store_image": "baker_stores_images/pUZtdPNCKoQnXbKWBwUnciK7Yo01fG1IMUggzgVK.png",
      "store_name": "test",
      "status": 1,
      "peyk_price": 0,
      "minimum_order": 1,
      "maximum_order": 1,
      "maximum_queue_count": 1,
      "morning_start_time": 1,
      "morning_end_time": 1,
      "afternoon_start_time": 1,
      "afternoon_end_time": 1,
      "active": 1,
      "bread": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "bread_name":"test",
          "image": "breads/AJq3PHo6Ja4AkcuSsJgyvUoUi4XGOTsmplgqhgEp.png",
          "price": 10000,
          "gram": "250",
          "bread_type": "test"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "bread_name": "test",
          "image": "breads/AJq3PHo6Ja4AkcuSsJgyvUoUi4XGOTsmplgqhgEp.png",
          "price": 10000,
          "gram": "200",
          "bread_type": "test"
        }
      ],
      "province": {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "test"
      },
      "city": {
        "id": 729,
        "province_id": 19,
        "name": "test"
      },
      "neighbourhood": {
        "id": 2,
        "city_id": 729,
        "name": "test"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

## UPDATED

my repository to get data from server:

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getResponse(
    HTTP method, String endPoint, Map<String, dynamic>? parameters) async {
  try {
    const r = RetryOptions(maxAttempts: 3);
    final response = await r.retry(
      () => _submit(method, endPoint, parameters),
      retryIf: (e) => e is SocketException || e is TimeoutException,
    );
    return {'statusCode': response.statusCode, 'data': response.data};
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    throw (e.response != null
        ? e.response!.statusCode
        : e.error.osError.errorCode) as Object;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `success['data'].map` is not list, try this:

```
final onlineBakers = success['data'].map((data) =>
UserModel.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>),).toList();
```

Comment: success['map'] is a List as an array

Comment: success['map']  means success is a map and it has a key that named map, but as I see in your question, success has key named data which its value is a list. and you can run a map operator on it then you should make all its item to a list.

Comment: map operator return you Iterable, not list.

Comment: `success['data']` is `return {'statusCode': response.statusCode, 'data': response.data};` could you please see my updated post again?

Comment: ok, success['data'] return you response.data? if yes, could please print this: success['data']

Comment: @yes, i pasted that into my post as a `json` response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247961/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-doldurma).

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you please up vote and approve it so other people find it easier.@DolDurma

Answer (score 0):

It's not as elegant as all in a row, but the type of each variable will be stated.

```
var onlineBakers = <UserModel>[];
var data = success['data'];
if(data is List){
  for(var item in data){
    if(item is Map){
      onlineBakers.add(UserModel.fromJson(item);
    }
  }
}
```